# Build tree from foreach loop php

Tags: php, arrays

I have following foreach loop :

```
foreach($mydata as $data){
    $section = $data->section;
    $category = $data->category;
    $item = $data->item;
}
```

I want to build tree like this :

```
- section
    _ category
        - items
...
```

For now i did like this :

```
$tmp = [];
$newarray = [];
foreach($mydata as $data){
    $section = $data->section;
    $category = $data->category;
    $item = $data->item;
    if( !in_array($category, $temp)){
        $newarray[$section][] = $category;
    } 
}

// output:
Array(
    [SectionName_one] => Array(
        [0] => categoryOneName_one
        [1] => categoryOneName_two
        [2] => categoryOneName_three
    )
    [SectionName_two] => Array(
        [0] => categoryTwoName_one
        [1] => categoryTwoName_two
        [2] => categoryTwoName_three
    )
    ...
)
```

And i am blocked here, i don't know how to insert items elements for each category, if you hava an idea thanks to help me :)

Thank you

Comment: `$newarray[$section][$category][] = $item`? Not really 100% sure what you're after.

Comment: Adding to what @JonStirling said, you can simply do this inside `foreach` loop, `$newarray[$data->section][$data->category][] = $data->item;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($mydata as $data){
    $newarray[$data->section][$data->category][]= $data->item;
}
```

PHP is quite forgiving with non-existent array keys.

Comment: ouch, great, thanks for your working solution, it works perfectly as i need .